# How to store data from a form written in HTML and JavaScript in a session or cookie using PHP to preload whenever the form is accessed

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I need to be able to save the data from a form into a session or cookie. Im not sure which would suit me best. Basically I have this form that consists of a lot of questions. This form is intended for users to complete in multiple sessions. It would be ideal for the user to answer the questions and then be able to close out the form and when they return at a later date the previous answered questions will appear. Im not too knowledgeable about php session/cookies some advice or even a small example would be greatly appreciated. I will be using XAMP to be able to execute the php.

I've tried doing some research on how to implement this but. I have not gotten anywhere.

Comment: In JavaScript, you can save the form information in the `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` or in a `cookie` and then, when the page loads, easily fill the form with the information that are found. Just remember: with `sessionStorage` the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed; with `localStorage` the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your app clears the data; while using a cookie the data is persisted until the user manually clears them (and they need to accept it first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [browser's local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), reading out the storage with Javascript `onload` and saving your form data to the storage `onbeforeunload`.